# return null for parameter if not exist

Tags: javascript, sql

I have next code:

```
  const {value: myValue} = await db.queryFirstRow(
    `SELECT value FROM some_table
            WHERE id = 1`);
```

When I am trying to select value which not exists it throws exception: `Cannot destructure property 'value' of '(intermediate value)' as it is null`.
How I can make this query to put null in to `myValue` and do not throw exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always expect one row, then one solution is in the SQL.  Use aggregation so one row is always returned:

```
SELECT MAX(value) as value
FROM some_table
WHERE id = 1;
```

If `id = 1` does not exist, then this will return one row with a `NULL` vaule.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nullish coalescing operator (??)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to provide default value in case of `null`.

```
const {value: myValue} = (await db.queryFirstRow(
`SELECT value FROM some_table WHERE id = 1`)) ?? {value: null};
```

If it is not available, you can use [`logical OR (||) operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Logical_OR_2) to provide default value in case of `null`. You may encounter unexpected behaviors if you consider some `falsy` values as usable (eg. `''` or `0`).

```
const {value: myValue} = (await db.queryFirstRow(
`SELECT value FROM some_table WHERE id = 1`)) || {value: null};
```